# htaccess Redirect Scenario, featuring WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm no good at anything that requires regular expressions - this includes redirects.

I need to redirect all subpages to a particular subpage. Everything I've tried either fails or causes an infinite redirect loop.

Example: Say I want everything under the domain to redirect to www.test.com/fubar (but obviously not /fubar)

This seems like it should be super easy. Anyone?

[Update]

I've tried everything posted so far, and nothing works. What's happening is that the pages are not redirecting and also not loading stylesheets. I think it has something to do with the rest of the htaccess file, which contains stuff for WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-content/blogs.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like this:

```
# Don't rewrite anything in /fubar
RewriteRule ^fubar - [L]
# Redirect everything to /fubar
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /fubar/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewrteRule !^/?fubar$ /fubar
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fubar/ - [L] // protect from loop, not sure if its really necessary
RewriteRule ^.*$ fubar/$0 [L,QSA]
```

Now to redirect only if the file path as given from the user does not exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ fubar/$0 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do using proxies:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://www.test.com/fubar/
ProxyPassReverse / http://www.test.com/fubar/
```